# Like statement with OR and Inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Here are my two tables and passengerId in table 1 (ticketperpassenger) is connected with id in table 2 (passengers). I want to select all from table 1 where PNR like %something% or fName like %something%. Means either something can be like PNR or like fName in table 2.

Here is the query:

```
select ticketperpassenger.* from request where PNR like '%something%' or passengers inner join passengers.id=requestperpassenger.passengerId where passengers.fName like %something%
```

Comment: if I have the solution query I'll screenshot that and add it as an answer? (or, you could use text instead of images, fixed width tables are easy to add to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax for join and where is not correct

```
select t.* 
from ticketperpassenger t
inner join passengers p on p.id=t.passengerId 
where t.PNR like '%something%' 
or p.fName like '%something%'
```

join statements comes before `where`  and keyword `where` is used only once, If you have multiple criteria then after where use `and` / `or`

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã can you post the error message, Also `on` clause was missing which i saw now, try the updated one